# libf.lib, console.lib and so on

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

Where can I get old Fortran libraries like libf.lib or console.lib? I keep getting an error from Digital Visual Fortran

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "libf.lib"
```

I googled for it for an hour, no luck.

Comment: If you have (the now archaic) Digital Visual Fortran, do you not have, somewhere within the installation directories, copies of the libraries you seek ?

Comment: How did you install DVF?

Comment: @VladimirF I installed DVF from a package downloaded ages ago. As I found, these libraries are only needed to rebuild other static libraries created in even more archaic Fortran Power Station. DVF does not need them in any other cases. Now I just moved to Power Station and it has all needed libraries. Thanks for your attention.